# Calculate duration between first login and last logout from a set of records in datatable

Tags: c#, linq, excel, ado.net

I am reading an Excel document using ADO.Net into a Dataset. Dataset Contains set of employee records which contains login and logout time as a Datatable. I need to fetch the employees's first login and last logout time as final record from the set of records based on employee id and date. Here is my example data:

```
    Emp Id  Name            Login             Logout
    12345   RAMACHANDRAN    7/30/2013 8:40  7/30/2013 10:40
    12345   RAMACHANDRAN    7/30/2013 12:30 7/30/2013 14:20
    12345   RAMACHANDRAN    8/01/2013 18:10 8/01/2013 20:20
    12345   RAMACHANDRAN    8/01/2013 20:40 8/01/2013 22:00
    12346   RAVI            8/03/2013 12:30 8/03/2013 14:20
    12346   RAVI            8/03/2013 18:10 8/03/2013 20:20
```

I need the final record with calculated duration as

```
 Emp Id    Name          Login           Logout            Duration
 12345   RAMACHANDRAN   7/30/2013 8:40  7/30/2013 14:20    5:40
 12345   RAMACHANDRAN   8/01/2013 18:10 8/01/2013 22:00    3:50
 12346   RAVI           8/03/2013 12:30 8/03/2013 20:20    7:50
```

Is it the best way to use Linq for querying this dataset? Which way is the best

Comment: I think linq query is the best way. check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399365.aspx.

Comment: Use a select statement to retrieve a "new" object with the minimum login and maximum logout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
dt.GroupBy(l => new {l.EmpId, l.Login.Date},
    (key, g)=> new {
             EmpId = key.EmpId,
             Name = g.First().Name,
             Login = g.Min(d => d.Login),
             Logout = g.Max(d => d.Logout),
             Duration = g.Min(d => d.Login) - g.Max(d => d.Logout)
     });
```

Comment: You need to group per date as well

Comment: Also note:

this works under the assumption that a user is not logged in at midnight,
if the user logs in and out multiple times a day `Duration` will be higher then the total time the user was logged in.

Comment: this query solved a lot of issues. thanks for everything. Learnt new things again. On a note: on c# if you are receiving incorrect min and max login logout time, make sure you convert them to datetime :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this,
I have to use the linq with list as bellow

```
 var ListValues = (from fDate in db.tblLog select fDate).Tolist(); 
foreach (var item in ListValues)
        {
            DateTime in = Convert.ToDateTime(inDate );
            DateTime out = Convert.ToDateTime(outDate );
            TimeSpan ts = in - out;
            var duration = ts.TotalHours;
        }
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question ... you are not using dataset, your not using linq, and above all you do not answer his need.